# accessing GeoPoint data from firestore document

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using react native and have firestore structured like this. and i want access the geopoint latitude and longitude. how do i do that? sorry i'm still newbie

```js
users:[{
    name:""
    geo_point:[latitude, longitutde]
  },
  {
    name:""
    geo_point:[latitude, longitutde]
  }]
```

i'm getting error with this code

```js
{this.state.users.map((user, idx) => <Marker 
            key={idx}
            coordinate={{latitude: user.geo_point[0], longitude: user.geo_point[1]}}
            >
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @jnpdx it says Error while updating property 'coordinate' of a view managed by AIRMapMarker null latitude

Comment: Okay, so user.geo_point[0] is `null` -- have you tried printing it out to console.log to see what is really in your `user` variable?

Comment: @jnpdx "geo_point": [Object] it printed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore `GeoPoint` is not an array; it's an object

you can access the lat & long using their field names, like below

```js
coordinate={{latitude: user.geo_point.latitude, longitude: user.geo_point.longitude}}
```